# Datatables with dynamic row generation

Tags: datatables, coldfusion, datatables-1.10

I'm using datatables 1.10.18 to show some data generated from a query. I loop over the first query and show some data and then I do another query inside the first query to get child rows to the main query. If I just show the data via a regular HTML table, it shows properly, for example, it may output 20 rows and maybe 5 have child rows and they get grouped together property. If I connect that table to datatables the child rows get shown first in the table. I'm using just this simple code to init databtables:

```
var table = $('.datatable-reporting').DataTable({
    autoWidth: true,
    scrollY: 300
});
```

Here is my table code:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-xs datatable-reporting">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Method</th>
                <th>Issue/Action</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Response Deadline</th>
                <th>Assigned To</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>      
        <tbody>
            <cfoutput query="get_ic" group="stakeholder_id">
                <cfoutput group="sh_inquiry_id">
                    <CFQUERY name="getfollowups" datasource="#datasource#">
                    SELECT
                       followup_id, followup_date, followup_who, followup_type, followup_action, followup_close, followup_contact_id, followup_additional, followup_inquiry_id, type_of_contact_nm
                    FROM followup
                    LEFT join type_of_contact ON followup.followup_type = type_of_contact.toc_id
                    where followup_inquiry_id = '#get_ic.sh_inquiry_id#'
                    order by followup_inquiry_id asc
                    </CFQUERY>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Inquiry</td>
                        <td ><strong>#full_name#</strong></td>
                        <td >#sh_inquiry_id#</td>
                        <td >#dateformat(sh_inquiry_date, 'M/D/YY')#</td>
                        <td >#type_of_contact_nm#</td>
                        <td >
                            <cfset type_of_issue_inquiry_list = "">
                            <cfoutput>
                                <cfset type_of_issue_inquiry_list = listappend(type_of_issue_inquiry_list,TYPE_OF_ISSUE_name) >
                            </cfoutput>
                            #TYPE_OF_ISSUE_inquiry_LIST#
                        </td>
                        <td ><cfif sh_inquiry_fu eq 1><span class="badge badge-danger font-size-lg">Open</span><cfelse><span class="badge badge-info font-size-lg">Closed</span></cfif></td>
                        <td><cfif sh_inquiry_fudate eq "">N/A<cfelse>#dateformat(sh_inquiry_fudate, 'M/D/YY')#</cfif>
                        </td>
                        <td >#fullname#</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Followup</td>
                        <td >##</td>
                        <td >#followup_id#</td>
                        <td >#dateformat(followup_date, 'M/D/YY')#</td>
                        <td >#type_of_contact_nm#</td>
                        <td >#followup_action#</td>           
                        <td >##</td>
                        <td >##</td>
                        <td >##</td>
                    </tr>

                </cfoutput>
            </cfoutput>      
        </tbody>       
    </table>
</div>
```

Any Ideas as to why this is happening?

here are two screenshots showing the output:

This shows the output with datatables applied, notice the followup is at the top
[image: with datatables applied]

This is with no datatables, the followup is underneath the correct inquiry
[image]

Comment: Keep simplifying it until you narrow down the issue. Remove styles, remove span/strong, remove child rows, etc. With a few iterations you should be able to narrow down the issue.

Comment: You're saying the child rows get shown first only when using datatables.  So if you change nothing else except for commenting out the datatables init code, is that still a true statement?

Comment: It displays correctly when I remove Datatables...

Comment: Then that tells me the source of your problem likely exists with your how your table structure is interacting with datatables and not your ColdFusion code.  Can you also add your `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<th>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` to your question?

Comment: I added the full table....thanks for your help, I'm now trying to get both parent and child data in the get_ic query, if I get that I would no longer need the get followups query that you see in this code

Comment: Unfortunately I see nothing odd about your table structure.  Now you're certain it renders fine with the datatables init code commented out?  Are there any console errors displaying with the init code?

Comment: review the 2 pics I attached....nothing in console regarding datatables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the picture, because as they say, it's worth a thousand words, and the answer is in the picture.  As you'll notice, it defaulted to sorting on the `Type` column and "Followup" sorts before "Inquiry".  So the answer is to turn sorting off by adding the `ordering: false` option.

```
var table = $('.datatable-reporting').DataTable({
    ordering: false,
    autoWidth: true,
    scrollY: 300
});
```

Comment: OMG, Thank you , I can't believe that I overlooked that, sometimes another pair of eyes is all you need!! Thanks Again.

Comment: @sartis Yes, datatables is a great tool and I no longer build html tables without it.  However, sometimes it can frustrate the hell of you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a series of recommendations.

```
<cfoutput query="get_ic" group="stakeholder_id">
    <cfoutput group="sh_contact_id">
        <CFQUERY name="getfollowups" datasource="#datasource#">
```

1. The above code is a really bad way to get started. Work on getting `get_ic` query needs to be simpler. You are likely loading in all kinds of data you don't need.
2. Jumping into a `<cfquery` is strange. This further suggests that `get_ic` is not getting the data you need.
3. All this CSS in the tables might be good for the final product, but for the sake of debugging, get rid of it.
4. Speaking of things to get rid of, in the first round of development, don't even bother with Datatables. At this stage, it is likely that the HTML is not correct. Get the HTML right then worry about Datatables.
5. Or better yet, load the data into JSON, and apply that data to Datatables, it will scale better and you will be separating the presentation of the data from the data.
6. Speaking of presentation, Datatables has all kinds of presentation facilities. Per reason 3, get rid of the CSS.
7. Speaking of debugging, try to get `get_ic` to generate say 10 rows. See if you can get 10 rows to work right. From there you can build up to the hundreds or thousands that you need.